# Subsection title style

Tags: section-titles

How can i get this result? [image: img]

The subsection number is a part of subsection title and it begins from par indent. If subsection title is to long it continues from new line as normal text (It is not aligned to the left side as in normal TeX document).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Especially in your case, as different document classes provide different ways to customize the style of (sub)sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which works for English and the `article` class.

```
% subsectitleprob.tex  SE 623138

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% block paragraph for divisional titles (instead of hanging)
\renewcommand{\@hangfrom}[1]{\noindent #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Not too long section title}
Some cectional text.
\subsection{This is a subsection title that takes more than a single line to print}
Some subsectional text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine with russian! Thank you.